# Handling property change several layers down

Tags: .net, vb.net, events, properties, event-handling

I am new to events and handling them, and this is a simplified example of the structure I have:

```
Public Class Main
    Public world As World
    Public totalWorldMass As Double

    'this function needs to be called if mass changes on any object in the world.
    Sub RecalculateTotalMass()
        totalWorldMass = world.object1.mass + world.object2.mass + world.object3.mass
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class World
    Public Property object1 As objectWithMass
    Public Property object2 As objectWithMass
    Public Property object3 As objectWithMass

    'other properties and methods
End Class

Public Class ObjectWithMass
    Public Property name As String
    Public Property mass As Double

    'other properties and methods
End Class
```

Please disregard the flaws of structure itself - as I said, this is a simplified example, there are valid reasons to have this structure in the real code that are beyond the scope of this question.

In essence, what I need is for the `Main` to observe the `world`, and run `RecalculateTotalMass` if the mass changes in any of it's properties.

What I tried so far is to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` in the `ObjectWithMass` class, declare `object1`, `object2` and `object3` in the `World` class with `WithEvents`, and then have this function in the main:

```
Public Sub HandleMassPropertyChanges() Handles world.object1.PropertyChanged, world.object2.PropertyChanged, world.object3.PropertyChanged
    RecalculateTotalMass()
End Sub
```

However, I cannot access `world.object1.PropertyChanged` like this. I can reach only as deep as `world.PropertyChanged`. However, if I implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` in the `World` instead of the `ObjectWithMass`, the event does not get fired, because the property is an object, and only the internal property of that object is changed.

Ideally, I would like not to specify what objects to handle in the `HandleMassPropertyChanges()` - I would like it to be called if mass changes on ANY property in the `World`. Not sure if this can be achieved without reflection, though.

How should I implement this?

Comment: Ok, so maybe something in your simplified example is lost on me, but seems to be making this a little more complicated that needs be.  This situation I would make a readonly property on the World class that returns object1.mass + object2.mass + object3.mass (with appropriate checks to avoid exceptions).  Means the value is always right without having to deal with event handling

Comment: @Hursey, huh, that actually makes sense. Don't know why I didn't think of it. Still, it wouldn't hurt for me to understand how to do it with events as well, even though I might end up using the solution you suggested.

Comment: Can you show us your implementation of INotifyPropertyChanged?

Comment: Interesting article on this subject. https://www.codemag.com/article/0907101/INotifyPropertyChanged-Is-Obsolete

Answer (score 3):

My two cents on the matter.
When you have nested objects that need to notify Property value changes, you may want to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` in all these objects.
Or, if using Windows Forms as GUI, follow the `PropertyName` / `PropertyNameChanged` pattern.
Both will let you bind all Properties that raise notification events.

Here's an alternative method, slightly less invasive, which make use of a simple Interface, which defines a method that is then called to generate all property change notifications.

```
Friend Interface IWorldModel
    Sub OnPropertyChanged(sender As Object, propertyName As String)
End Interface
```

Implementing the Interface in the top-level model, you can get Property change notifications from all nested classes that are made aware of the existence of the Interface.
In this case, the `World` class receives notifications when the `Name` and the `Mass` of any `ObjectWithMass` changes, so it can recalculate the `TotalMass` value, which also cause notification events (it also raises the `PropertyChanged` event).

In this implementation, all properties of all classes that are made aware of the Interface, can be used for data bindings (because all raise `PropertyChanged` notifications).
Unless the top-level class decides otherwise, based of whatever property value or any combination of values or other rules you can specify.

```
Friend Class World
    Implements IWorldModel
    Implements INotifyPropertyChanged

    Public Event PropertyChanged As PropertyChangedEventHandler Implements INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged
    Private m_TotalMass As Double

    Public ReadOnly Property TotalMass As Double
        Get
            Return m_TotalMass
        End Get
    End Property

    Public Property Object1 As ObjectWithMass(Of IWorldModel)
    Public Property Object2 As ObjectWithMass(Of IWorldModel)
    Public Property Object3 As ObjectWithMass(Of IWorldModel)

    Protected Sub OnPropertyChanged(sender As Object, propertyName As String) Implements IWorldModel.OnPropertyChanged
        ' Using LINQ to get the value of the Mass properties. Any other method will do
        m_TotalMass = Me.GetType().GetProperties().
            Where(Function(p) p.PropertyType.IsGenericType AndAlso p.PropertyType.GenericTypeArguments.
                Any(Function(a) a.IsAssignableFrom(GetType(IWorldModel)))).
            Sum(Function(p) DirectCast(p.GetValue(Me), ObjectWithMass(Of IWorldModel))?.Mass).Value

        RaiseEvent PropertyChanged(sender, New PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName))
        RaiseEvent PropertyChanged(Me, New PropertyChangedEventArgs(NameOf(TotalMass)))
    End Sub
End Class
```

Any class that defines a nested object type can then call the method specified by the Interface, the top-level class will intercept all notifications calls and decide what to do.

Clearly, your `ObjectWithMass` objects, in this implementation, are strictly tied to the top-level class and the Interface it implements.

```
Friend Class ObjectWithMass(Of T As IWorldModel)
    Private m_Name As String
    Private m_Mass As Double
    Private m_World As T

    Sub New(world As T, name As String, mass As Double)
        m_World = world
        Me.Name = name
        Me.Mass = mass
    End Sub

    Public Property Name As String
        Get
            Return m_Name
        End Get
        Set
            If m_Name <> Value Then
                m_Name = Value
                m_World.OnPropertyChanged(Me, NameOf(Name))
            End If
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property Mass As Double
        Get
            Return m_Mass
        End Get
        Set
            If m_Mass <> Value Then
                m_Mass = Value
                m_World.OnPropertyChanged(Me, NameOf(Mass))
            End If
        End Set
    End Property
End Class
```

To create a `World` class object and assign the value of one of its properties, specify the Interface type and the parent class object that implements it:

```
Private worldObject As World = Nothing
' [...]
worldObject = New World()
worldObject.Object1 = New ObjectWithMass(Of IWorldModel)(worldObject, "World 1", 100.84545)
'[...]
```

This is how it works, when Controls (WinForms, here) are bound to the top-level class:

[image: DataBindings Nested Classes]

Comment: thank you very much for taking the time to write such an elaborate example with a clear explanation. Although this is very complicated, it taught me a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Change `totalWorldMass` to be a readonly property that returns the sum of the properties:

```vb
Public ReadOnly Property totalWorldMass As Double
    Get
        Return world.object1.mass + world.object2.mass + world.object3.mass
    End Get
End Property
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/O9QHst

Comment: Yeah, that would work, @Hursey suggested the same thing. But still, for learning purposes, I would also like to know how to do this with events, even if it's not as optimal for this specific case.